# Make input control invisible and keep input functionality

Tags: html, css

I wonder, if I could make **HTML FORM input controls invisible**, while **keeping their input text-editing functionality active**.

Why? Because a designer created an image, which should be used as a form. The image make use of color gradients - all over and inside the form fields.

Comment: if you make it INVISIBLE then you won't even see the text they input...it's better to remove its border and to make its background transparent (on browsers where it's available)

Comment: Yeah, exactly this is the reason I asked...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
input{
    background:transparent;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stTER/).

To keep input (text-editing) functionality and to hide it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try some styling like this for a textfield:

```
input[type="text"] {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
}
```

**Note:** Transparency does not work by default in IE6.